# Initialize variables with resharper

Tags: c#, formatting, resharper

Is there a way to configure resharper to initialize variables?

E.g. this

```
bool notInitialized;
```

Should become this

```
bool notInitialized = false;
```

Comment: That doesn't make much sense, how would it know to what you want it to be initialized to ? Programmers are typist after all :http://blog.codinghorror.com/we-are-typists-first-programmers-second/

Comment: In your specific example Resharper would suggest removing the assignment anyway, as `bool`s are initialised to `false`. :)